# How to impose a space in HTML

Tags: html, whitespace

I have a blue bar with menu items going across the top. However, I have been tasked with creating an item that functions essentially as a return to the home page. Below is the code needed for that. It works fine. The issue is that I need to impose a space between the pre-existing menu bar across the top and this item. I have tried adding the following

```
  <p>
  </p>
```

prior to the code below but only the first instance has any effect. Any other suggestions?

If you need an example of this pre-existing menu bar (or whatever it is called), go to http://www.laworks.net/labormarketinfo/lmi_mainmenu.asp

```
            <div class="row tab-cover">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a id="bottom"></a>
            <a href="/ds#ds" target="_self">Return to Categories</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
            <p>To Download Table Data Click on the Table then Select 
             Download.
            </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: add a <br /> tag to do a line break

Comment: @Cubemaster, Can you submit that as an answer so you can get credit. That works

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Make sur e you mark it as the accepted answer if it helped. Gives both of us reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<br />` tag to create whitespace.